# Jpeg plugin not loading in PySide/Qt

Tags: python, qt, macos, pyside

I'm at wits end trying to figure out why my Qt install will not display JPEG. Initially I noticed when PySide would not display the image. I built a simplified version in both c++ **and** python, none work.
I've tried qt.conf but no-go. I don't know what else to try, but I do know that it's not **just** PySide.

P.S. this is on os x 10.6.7 with xcode4
http://www.mediafire.com/?79vhbwwvmilwm2o - .tar.bz2 containing my code. It'll load an image called `test`, which works fine for png's not jpeg's

Answer (score 2):

Try to include PySides plugin directory with: app.addLibraryPath(pathToPluginDirectory)

Answer (score 0):

Probably Qt was built without jpeg support. From where did you install it?